# If I have two machine learning model instances of the same architecture, there is any feature to store only the difference between these two models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, distributed-computing

I know that it is possible, for example using TensorFlow but also in PyTorch or whatever, to store an instance of a trained (or in training) model in a way that it can be loaded in future, or loaded by another machine, or just to use it as a checkpoint during the training.

What I wonder is if there is any way, such as the above mentioned one, to store the difference (maybe not exactly the algebric subtraction but a similar concept, always referring to operation on tensors) between two instances of the same neural network (same architecture, different weights) for efficiency purposes.
If you are wondering why this should be convenient, consider an hypothetical setting where there are different entities and all of them know a model instance (a "shared model"), so using the "difference" calculated with respect to this shared model could be useful in terms of storage space or in terms of bandwidth (if the local model parameters should be sent via Internet to another machine).
The hypotesis is that it is possible to reconstruct a model knowing the shared model and the "difference" with the model to reconstruct.

Summarizing my questions:

- There is any built-in features in TensorFlow, Pytorch, etc.. to do this?
- It could be convenient in your opinion to do something like that? If not, why?

PS: In literature, this concept exists and it has been recently explored within the "Federated Learning" topic, and the "difference" I mentioned is called *update*.

Comment: It's interesting although a bit too broad. In principle, the differences would take as much space as the weights. If differences are supposed to be small maybe you could store them at lower precision, but it's hard to assess that. Beyond that, you would need to find a pattern in the difference, e.g. "this polynomial approximates model B from A", but in general that may not be possible. It's another thing if the model B is something like "the first model plus an additional specialization layer", or "replacing the last layer", which is something that has actually been done in the literature.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You are right, I have not been clear about difference and it could lead to think that a difference should take the same space, but some efforts have been made in literature, for example what are called *sketched updates* and *structured updates* in this paper by Google "FEDERATED LEARNING: STRATEGIES FOR IMPROVING COMMUNICATION EFFICIENCY",
Jakub Konecny, H. Brendan McMahan, Felix X. Yu, Ananda Theertha Suresh & Dave Bacon.

To give an idea (I am not an expert) using some compression technique as done for video compression for the mentioned *sketched updates*.

Comment: So I am wondering if there is something in Tensorflow and similar that implements what is explained and tested in litirature.

Comment: Chances are that when considering such sophisticated methods/algorithms, one needs to implement it themselves entirely in code. It is highly unlikely, especially with very recent research, that such functionality is readily available in any type of programming library.

Comment: @AlessioMora Thanks for the reference, I wasn't aware of such work. As BlueRine S suggests, this seems to be an area of active research, and it is unlikely to find off-the-shelf implementations for it. You could try to get in touch with the authors of that or some other publication to see if they have some software they can share, but it is usually the case that one has to implement experimental methods by hand for the particular objective problem.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for the heads-up, if I will actually need to use them I will try to contact the authors of the related literature, for now I am just investigating this interesting area.